# SASS/Compass Transitions

Tags: sass, compass-sass

Is it possible to use Compass or SASS to output the following CSS transition that will output all the various vendor prefixes:

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
```

Can anyone point me to the correct library?

Comment: compass indeed has a horrible documentation

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use [compass' `transition` mixin](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/transition/):

```
@include transition(all 0.3s ease-in-out);
```

Comment: In addition to the transitions linked by Joseph, if you're looking for animations, Eric Meyer has a [Compass Animation plugin](https://github.com/ericam/compass-animate) which requires [Compass v0.13](http://beta.compass-style.org/CHANGELOG/) (currently alpha)

Comment: `@include transition(color 0.3s ease-in-out, background-color 0.3s ease-in-out);` if you want to target specific styles (which I believe is faster)

Answer (score 6):

**Mixin for creating animations using single or "all" property transitions**

```
@include transition(PROPERTY DURATION DELAY(OPT) TIMING-FUNCTION)
@mixin transition($transition) {
  -webkit-transition: $transition;
     -moz-transition: $transition;
      -ms-transition: $transition;
       -o-transition: $transition;
          transition: $transition;
}
```

**Mixin for creating animations using multiple property transitions**

```
@include multi-transition("PROPERTY DURATION DELAY(OPT) TIMING-FUNCTION, PROPERTY DURATION DELAY(OPT) TIMING-FUNCTION")
@mixin multi-transition($transition) {
 -webkit-transition: #{$transition};
    -moz-transition: #{$transition};
     -ms-transition: #{$transition};
      -o-transition: #{$transition};
         transition: #{$transition};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SASS Mixin

```
@mixin transition($transition){
     -webkit-transition: $transition;
     -moz-transition: $transition;
     -o-transition: $transition;
     transition: $transition;
}

@include transition(all 0.3s ease-in-out);
```